# Prisma : Models and Relationship 1-n

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2, plumatic-schema, prisma-binding

I have two tables `User` and `Tasks` and a user can have many tasks, however i want a query to return a particular task, fetching details for the task, with author and assigned to users from the user table, usually would be done using aliases. DB is mysql - Thanks

```
//schema.prisma

model User {
  id         Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  taskby     Task[] @relation("taskBy")
  taskto     Task[] @relation("taskTo")
}

model Task {
  id              Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  created_at      DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at      DateTime @updatedAt
  assigned_to_uid Int
  assigned_by_uid Int
  assigned_to     User     @relation("taskTo",fields: [assigned_to_uid], references: [id])
  assigned_by     User     @relation("taskBy",fields: [assigned_by_uid], references: [id])
}
```

API:

```
if (id) {
    res = await prisma.task.findUnique({
      where: { id },
      include: {
        assigned_to: true
      },
      include: {
        assigned_by: true
      },
    })
  } else {...
```

Desired Response:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "taskid": 2,
  "assigned_to_uid": 1,
  "assigned_by_uid": 2,
  "assigned_by": {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "user2",
  },
"assigned_to": {
    "id": 1
    "firstName": "user1",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the desired response by using the below query:

```js
  if (id) {
    const response = await prisma.task.findUnique({
      where: { id },
      include: {
        assigned_to: true,
        assigned_by: true,
      },
    });

    console.log(response);
  }
```

Response for the above query:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  created_at: 2022-02-28T07:22:06.917Z,
  updated_at: 2022-02-28T07:22:06.918Z,
  assigned_to_uid: 2,
  assigned_by_uid: 1,
  assigned_to: { id: 2, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' },
  assigned_by: { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already had the query in the api call block: - it was defining the  relationship that was trouble.<pre> model User {
 id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  taskby     Task[]   @relation(name: "taskby")
  taskto     Task[]   @relation(name: "taskto")
} </pre>